# gitignore continuing to ignore files after ignore pattern removed

Tags: gitignore

My changes to .gitignore are not causing git to add some files previously ignored

.gitignore had this in it

```
!import/
import/*
!import/*.foo
```

To have all but the foo files tracked.  This worked well.  However, I want all the files in import/ to be tracked now, so I commented those lines of .gitignore.

I now get this

```
craig@ubuntu-dev:<workspace>$ cd import
craig@ubuntu-dev:<workspace>/import$ git add .
craig@ubuntu-dev:<workspace>/import$ git commit -m "comment"
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I am a newbie.  Am I using git incorrectly or is there something I have to tell it to re-include the .gitignore or ?
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

This works by explicitly telling git to import these.
I presume git continues to track them after this.

> git add import/*